# Ruby on Rails - Make an AJAX request and render the partial of the resulting model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, partials

I have looked everywhere for an answer to my doubt, but none of them worked for me (I probably did something wrong).

I am very new to Ruby/Ruby on Rails, so I do not know very much how things work.

---

I have two models in my application

- `Attribute name:string` and;
- `Product name:string`.

I do also have two controllers:

- `attributes_controller` and;
- `products_controller`.

I also have the following view `../app/views/product_models/new.html.erb`. In this view, I want to be able to create an attribute and show it to the user right afterwards (using AJAX)

```
<div id="attributes_list">
  <%= render :partial => "attributes/attribute", :collection => @attributes, :as => :attribute %>
</div>

<div id="new_attribute">
  <strong>Adicionar novo atributo</strong> <br />
  Nome: <input type="text" class="name"><br />
  <span class="create_button">Criar</span>
</div>
```

for this situation, I have the following jquery (in `../app/assets/javascripts/application.js`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var new_attribute_div = $(document).find('#new_attribute')
    new_attribute_div.on('click', '.create_button', function () {
        // alert('funfou');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/attributes',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "script",
            data: {
                name: new_attribute_div.find(".name").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $(document)
                    .find('#attributes_list')
                    .append("<%= j render @attribute %>");

                new_attribute_div.find(".name").val("");

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error:" + data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my attributes_controller is just like this

```
class AttributesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @attribute = Attribute.new(attribute_params)
    @attribute.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @attribute }
      format.js
      format.json
    end
  end
end

private
def attribute_params
  params.permit(:name)
end
```

The problem I am having is, when the following line of the jquery is executed

```
.append("<%= j render @attribute %>");
```

Instead of rendering the partial of the attribute, rails is rendering the string itself (*<%= j render @attribute %>*)

What am I doing wrong? 
How can I render the @attribute that is returned from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use rails snippets or variables in assets

```
"<%= j render @attribute %>"
```

To fix this, you have to have `.js.erb` file in `attributies/create.js.erb`

In the file pass your render attribute

```
$(document)
      .find('#attributes_list')
      .append("<%= j render @attribute %>"
```

Remember, this will trigger only when request comes as JS.

Comment: Perfect answer, @7urkm3n! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

Augusto,
You should have the Rails part of the code inside jquery within #{ }
so it should be:

```
.append("#{<%= j render @attribute %>}");
```